# Solve equation $y^{(iv)}+y=1$ with Laplace

Tags: laplace-transform

help me with this exercises,

Laplace transform $$y^{(iv)}+y=1$$ with 
$\ \ \ \ \ y(0)=y'(0)=y''(0)=y'''(0)=0$

---

I got

$$Y(s)=\frac{1}{s(s^4+1)}$$
But, I don't know how to continue:

$s^4+1=(s^2+\sqrt2 s+1)(s^2-\sqrt2 s+1)$

help :(

.

.

Comment: The Laplace transform of $1$ is not $1$.

Comment: mm,, yes is 1/s

Comment: @Moo how do you parse $y^{(iv)} + y = 1$ ? (and I guess this is $y^{(iv)} + y = 1_{t > 0}$)

Comment: @Moo what means $y^{(iv)}$... it is obvious come on (and IC means nothing to me)

Comment: nobody writes it like that.. $y^{(4)}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** As you wrote, by taking Laplace from your equation, we obtained $$Y(s)=\frac{1}{s(s^4+1)}$$ Then, using partial fractions, we have $$Y(s)=\dfrac{1}{s} - \dfrac{s^3}{s^4+1}$$ Can you continue by taking inverse Laplace from this to find $y(t)$?

Comment: Indeed you solved it! This is beyond a hint. :-)

Comment: what? Is the inverse Laplace transform of $s^3/(s^4+1)$ obvious? It seems to me this still needs to be ripped into a sum of two irreducible quadratics reciprocals... so, I think this is a hint.